# Calculated field for month over month percentage change

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering what the formula is to put into the calculated field to returns the percentage change for the current month vs the previous? I know you can do this quite easily in excel but I haven't yet found a way to do so in google sheets.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: proposal here below]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oHyyiFRx6w0TMBfKUCFhp7ApzSQXkoBGm8pSzhwlbzM/edit#gid=458664666

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you :)